# Beautiful Soup find specific tr tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How do I find specific `tr` tags within a table body?  For instance consider the following:

```
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3" class="tablehead">
   <tbody>
    <tr class="stathead">...</tr>
    <tr class="colhead">...</tr>
    <tr class="oddrow team-23-2046">...</tr>
    <tr class="evenrow team-22-1234">...</tr>
    <tr class="oddrow team-25-2326">...</tr>
    <tr class="evenrow team-25-2262">...</tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I need all the "oddrow" and "evenrow" tags but not the "stathead" or "colhead".  I was able to do something like this with a slice:

```
for data in soup.find_all("table", {"class": "tablehead"}):
    for row in data.find_all('tr')[2:]:
        print(row.text)
```

But I'm not always sure that every page where I'm scrapping that content will have this format so I'd rather explicitly search for "oddrow/evenrow".  The team numbers are also different for every page so I can't use those numbers for an exact match.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Why not just get the TR, and then test the class attr if it starts with 'o' or 'e'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
soup.find("table", {"class": "tablehead"}).find_all("tr", {"class": ["oddrow", "evenrow"]})
```

*Example*:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup("""<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="3" class="tablehead">
   <tbody>
    <tr class="stathead">...</tr>
    <tr class="colhead">...</tr>
    <tr class="oddrow team-23-2046">...</tr>
    <tr class="evenrow team-22-1234">...</tr>
    <tr class="oddrow team-25-2326">...</tr>
    <tr class="evenrow team-25-2262">...</tr>
   </tbody>
</table>""", "html.parser")

soup.find("table", {"class": "tablehead"}).find_all("tr", {"class": ["oddrow", "evenrow"]})
#[<tr class="oddrow team-23-2046">...</tr>,
# <tr class="evenrow team-22-1234">...</tr>,
# <tr class="oddrow team-25-2326">...</tr>,
# <tr class="evenrow team-25-2262">...</tr>]
```

Comment: I'll give that a try. BS really confuses me. I don't really have much html coding knowledge so I really struggle when it comes to this.